# RDLC not displayed properly when deployed

Tags: asp.net, iis, rdlc

RDLC displays properly on localhost, but fields/objects in the report are not displayed properly when the report is deployed to IIS.

Here are sample screenshots:

[image: localhost]

[image: deployed]

I already installed reportviewer runtime 2015 on the iis server.

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure all the files related to RDLC are there in the published files, you can try to use F12 to view the console, there should be relevant error messages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also as observed, the font seemed to be bigger in the deployed version.

Comment: This issue has been solved. For future reference, my mistake was I installed the missing fonts by double clicking them and clicking install. To fix this, right click the font and click 'Install for all users'